# How to pass data on route navigate in submit function (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have a submit function, when i submit i get data from the server.
I want that the data that i receive will pass to other components.

This is my function

```
  submitForm(partner, manager, taxDevision, taxYear, standard, date) {
    const type = 1;
    if (partner && manager && taxDevision && taxYear && standard && date.value !== null && this.addValue !== '') {
      const day = date.value.getDate();
      const month = date.value.getMonth() + 1;
      const year = date.value.getFullYear();
      const newDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
      this.reportsService.createNewReport(this.addValue, type, taxYear, newDate, (data) => this.onCreateReportSuccess(data));
    } else {
      this.errorLabel = 'Fill all field';
    }
  }
  onCreateReportSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/kit']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more what you mean by other components ?
At first sight, i'd say you can add the data you received from the POST response to a BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject in your service.
Then subscribe to this Observable in your other components.

Comment: When i submit the form i get data. i want to send the data to "kit" component, then i want to do somthing in "kit" component

Comment: You could use a shared service: here you store it in the service, and in the kit component you retrieve it

Comment: Using a rxJs pipe in your service, you can plug onto Http call's Observable and store the response in a https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html

Comment: From Angular 7 you can use "Navigation Extras", the officials doc are not clearly, but check this link: https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
  submitForm(partner, manager, taxDevision, taxYear, standard, date) {
    const type = 1;
    if (partner && manager && taxDevision && taxYear && standard && date.value !== null && this.addValue !== '') {
      const day = date.value.getDate();
      const month = date.value.getMonth() + 1;
      const year = date.value.getFullYear();
      const newDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
      this.reportsService.createNewReport(this.addValue, type, taxYear, newDate, (data) => this.onCreateReportSuccess(data));
    } else {
      this.errorLabel = 'Fill all field';
    }
  }
  onCreateReportSuccess(data) {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/kit'], { queryParams: data[0] });
  }
```

Get the Data on Kit component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(reportData => {
        console.log(this.reportData);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the following service implementation

```
export class ReportService{
    postedReport: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    ...
    createNewReport(...){
        return this.http.post(...).pipe(tap((response)=>{
            this.postedReports.next(response);
        }));
    }

}
```

Using rxjs [pipe](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/pipe) and [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html?q=) we plug into the async response and store it in a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html).

Then reproducing this extract from your original code,

```
export class componentA{
    constructor(public reportService: ReportService,...){}
    ...
    submitForm(){
        this.reportService.createNewReport(...)
        .toPromise().then(() => console.log('post'));
    }
}
```

Here finally , We can read our service response value in componentB

```
export class componentB{
    constructor(public reportService: ReportService,...){
        let sub = this.reportService.postedReport.subscribe((report)=>{

                    console.table(report);
                  })
    }
    ...
    printReport(){
        console.log(this.reportService.postedReport.value)
    }
}
```

Please note that these examples are incomplete, and we make use of placeholders like [...]

As response to the OPs need of binding to componentA's
service call reponse in componentB. Not using the navigate function as suggested, since we are in the same angular application, service also works, and has the advance of separating navigation from data query and storage.